# Deep copy Realm object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I wanna duplicate realm object and then change the second, without reassigning all the keys. How can I do this? `RealmObject` does not have `.copy()` or `.clone()` methods.

```
// Money is not data class and has ∞ fields which will be boring to re-assign

val money = Money()
money.amount = 1000

...

val anotherMoney = money
anotherMoney.amount = 500

println(money.amount) // prints 500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please provide more context and appropriate information as I do not see and array's in your code statement. Thank you.

## EDIT

Because Money is not a data class, you do not have the auto-generated copy() function available, that leaves you with two options:

1. Create an custom copy() function in the Money class. This could be mundane if there are huge amount of fields in the class.
2. Use 3rd party libraries, in which case you'll add external dependency to your RealmObject.

What I will suggest is a no brainer: Try to convert your Money.class to a Data class. You will get auto generated functions and idiomatically it will work as RealmObjects should be key-values pairs.

## EDIT

You can use GSON library's serialization/deserialization and hack your way to solve your problem (although this is a hacky way but will do its job):

```
fun clone(): Money {
  val stringMoney = Gson().toJson(this, Money::class.java)
  return Gson().fromJson<Money>(stringMoney, Money::class.java)
}
```

usage:

```
val originalMoney = Money()
val moneyClone = originalMoney.clone()
```

Comment: The code provided is the example. The array is just an extra case.

Comment: There is no variant to make RealmObject class `data class` because it needs to be `open class`. Could you please make an example of the 3rd party library for Kotlin that actually works? And I also can't find a proper example of copy() function. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: this should but this is not solving in my case, compiler is now intelligent to see if all values are same , it is not creating the new instance